# How to enforce the override keyword when overriding abstract members?

Tags: typescript, polymorphism, overriding, abstract, typescript-eslint

The TypeScript compiler offers the `noImplicitOverride` setting that, if set to `true`, will enforce the `override` keyword when overriding a non-abstract member. For example:

```ts
abstract class A {
  public doSomething(): void {
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public doSomething(): void { // TS4114
  }
}
```

Only when changing the problematic line to `public override doSomething(): void {` will the compiler be satisfied. Excellent!

---

The same, however, does not hold when the inherited method happens to be abstract:

```ts
abstract class A {
    public abstract doSomething(): void;
}

class B extends A {
    public doSomething(): void { // no error
    }
}
```

**Is there any obscure way in the TS compiler options to enforce the `override` keyword here, as well? Alternatively, I could not find any TypeScript-ESLint rule to enforce this, or is there any?**

Comment: There are no TS compiler options that do what you want.  The current behavior is considered intentional as per https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44457.  There's an open feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47250 asking for a way to require `override` on implementations of abstract properties, marked as "awaiting more feedback"; if enough people comment and like that issue then maybe this will eventually happen.

Comment: I would write this up as an answer but I don't have authoritative knowledge about the TS-eslint part, and it seems your question is about both pieces.  If you could focus on just tsc or on eslint, then I could answer (or not, depending on which one you pick).  Otherwise, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the questions directly: no. There is no way as of TypeScript 5.3 or typescript-eslint 6.18.1 to enforce an `override` keyword when implementing `abstract` class methods.

If you'd like this to exist, there are a few options:

- As @jcalz mentions, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47250 tracks a feature request on TypeScript itself to do this - no guarantees that'll land soon or ever.
- You could [file an issue on typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/new/choose) to have it considered as a core rule for typescript-eslint. No guarantees on success or timeliness on this one either.
- In the meantime, you could [build a custom lint rule with typescript-eslint's tooling](https://typescript-eslint.io/developers/custom-rules) and release it as your own standalone ESLint plugin npm package.

That last one is what I'd recommend if you don't want to wait another 1.5 years.